# HTML button (using Google's material-icons) is rendering too small on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a simple HTML page with a button in the bottom right corner. The code I used is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dummy Page</title>
    <style>
        /* Style for the container */
        .rb-button-container {
          position: fixed; /* Fix the position */
          bottom: 20px; /* Distance from the bottom */
          right: 20px; /* Distance from the right */
          z-index: 9999; /* Ensure it's above other elements if needed */
        }
        /* Centering the content */
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }

    </style>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

</body>

<div class="rb-button-container">
<button style="background-color: #3498db; color: white; border-radius: 20px; padding: 10px 10px; border: none;">
<span class="material-icons">
    question_answer
    </span>
</button>
</div>
</html>
```

```html
<style>
  /* Style for the container */
  
  .rb-button-container {
    position: fixed;
    /* Fix the position */
    bottom: 20px;
    /* Distance from the bottom */
    right: 20px;
    /* Distance from the right */
    z-index: 9999;
    /* Ensure it's above other elements if needed */
  }
  /* Centering the content */
  
  body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Hello World</h1>
<div class="rb-button-container">
  <button style="background-color: #3498db; color: white; border-radius: 20px; padding: 10px 10px; border: none;">
    <span class="material-icons">
        question_answer
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The button renders correctly in desktop browers but looks very (very!) tiny in mobile browsers. What I am doing wrong? I thought Google's Materials Icon stylesheet takes care of rendering it correctly depending on browser. Please help!

Comment: Please test the added snippet in your mobile device. In fact your code has some severe nesting issues as you added code outside the body. Otherwise inspect your code via dev tools emulating a mobile device. It might be a misconfigured mediaquery as well causing the problem.

Comment: thanks @herrstrietzel. the snippet renders normall in a mobile but my guess (keeping in mind my limited HTML / CSS / Front-end knowledge) is that the viewport for the snippet window is more similar to a desktop than a mobile? I checked in dev tools and the button renders tiny (just like it did on my Android and iOS). it seems the font-size (which is read from the Google stylesheet) is always 24px. There are no media queries configured in their stylesheet?

Comment: The font size is at a fixed 24px. But Im not sure what size you're aiming at. maybe you should add a screenhot mockup (wrong/too tiny, vs. desired rendering)

Comment: here are a couple of screen shots: https://myscreencapture.s3.amazonaws.com/mobile_browser.png  https://myscreencapture.s3.amazonaws.com/desktop_browser.png

Comment: the button looks "normal" in the desktop screen shot but it looks tiny in the mobile screen shot (I drew a red circle which to me would make it look normal). I am not an expert on responsive design but shouldn't the google stylesheet have relative units instead of fixed units? or at least media queries?

Comment: Can you test this [page to get your androids screen resolution?](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/rNPEEbw). From your screenshot it seems your screen is either gigantic or it has some zoom level applied (the H1 is also very small)

Comment: using my laptop:
Hello World resolution is: 1280 x 720 - density: 1.5

using my mobile:
Hello World resolution is: 360 x 780 - density: 3

Comment: @herrstrietzel, I added your script to my dummy page and uploaded it to see what the screen resolution is. It is as expected and yet it still shows the buttom super tiny. here's the updated screen capture: https://myscreencapture.s3.amazonaws.com/updated_mobile.jpg

Comment: I also tried to look at this page in dev tools and noticed that he "body" element is showing as 980 x 2014 (is that the same thing as the viewport?). Here is a screen capture: https://myscreencapture.s3.amazonaws.com/dev_tools.jpeg

Comment: this may be a stupid question, but could I be missing a tag in the HTML header to specify overall viewport, etc.? I was doing some research, would I need to add something like this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing could be related to the default font size of the Material Icons or the way the button size is being calculated. You can set a fixed font size for the Material Icons and adjust the button size accordingly. In below code  I added a specific font size for the Material Icons class, and I increased the padding of the button for better visibility on mobile devices. Feel free to adjust the values according to your design preferences.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dummy Page</title>
    <style>
        /* Style for the container */
        .rb-button-container {
          position: fixed; /* Fix the position */
          bottom: 20px; /* Distance from the bottom */
          right: 20px; /* Distance from the right */
          z-index: 9999; /* Ensure it's above other elements if needed */
        }
        /* Centering the content */
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }

        /* Fixed font size for Material Icons */
        .material-icons {
            font-size: 24px; /* Adjust the size as needed */
        }
    </style>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <div class="rb-button-container">
        <button style="background-color: #3498db; color: white; border-radius: 20px; padding: 14px 14px; border: none;">
            <span class="material-icons">
                question_answer
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know the status.

Comment: I added the Font Size for Material Icons but it didn't help. The button still renders like a (big) dot on my mobile browser. Shouldn't font-size be managed by the Google-provided stylesheet?

Comment: Actually I just tried different font-sizes (including double the above font size) but that's not impacting the way the button is being rendered. Something is overriding that?

Comment: @Bas: You should move the custom `<style>` after the gfont CSS link - otherwise it will override your custom rules. If you open the google link you can see it includes a `.material-icons` class rule applying a fixed font-size (24px). Frankly I can't reproduce this error at least not in ios safari

Comment: Noted. Thanks @herrstrietzel. Stll rendering a very tiny button (on both Android and iOS). I have no clue why!

Comment: Hi! Sometimes, styles with higher specificity can override your intended styles. You can increase the specificity of your styles to ensure they take precedence. For an example, `body .material-icons {
    font-size: 24px;
}`